# Change color of an anchor when clicked

Tags: javascript, html, css

i want that when i click this link its color changes to the given color

```
<li id="press"><a href="<?=base_url()?>index.php/page/press">Press</a></li>
```

Comment: Could you explain whether you want to change element's text colour and do nothing more or maybe go to URL specified by `href` and have coloured link on that page?

Comment: yes...dats exactly i want...link should be active wenever i click on dat link...

Answer (score 6):

The CSS declaration `:active` will accomplish what you're after. http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pseudo_active.asp

**Example.**

```
a:active {
    color: #C00;
}
```

**NB.**

`a:active` MUST come after `a:hover` in the CSS definition in order to be effective!

Answer (score 3):

Here is the sample Css for the visited hyperlink

```
a:link {color:#FF0000}    
a:visited{color:Red}
```

Hope that will help.

Comment: -1 It's not - Richa wants the colour to change when clicked, not after.

Comment: Then you can use
a:active{color:Red}

Hope that will help

Answer (score 2):

All links? `a:focus { color: orange; }`

Some links? Give them a class, eg `<a class="foo" ...>`: `a.foo:focus { color: purple; }`

One link? Give it an id, eg `<a id="bar" ...>`: `a#bar:focus { color: #BADA55; }`

Comment: `a:focus` is incorrect. The `:focus` pseudo-class adds special style to an element that has keyboard input focus. http://www.w3schools.com/CSS/pr_pseudo_focus.asp And the question is **Change color of an anchor when clicked**

Comment: @Haynes: `:focus` refers to caret focus, which is applied after the link becomes active (`:active` is transitory). That is, the caret moves to the last-clicked position.

Answer (score -3):

You can accomplish that at server-side with PHP or with JS.

With PHP all you need is to added a given classname to the link once clicked.
a very simple example would be:

```
<a href="myURL" class="<?php if(ExpressionToDetermineIfLinkIsClicked) echo 'selected'; ?>">
```

and CSS:

```
.selected { color: #FF0000; }
```

If you would like to do it with JS , and you are using any JS Framework just search the frameworks' site for "How to add an event"  & "How to add classname" then combine what you get to know from the search results.

If you are, by coincidence, using prototype.js framework,
then you can try the following:

```
function selectLink(link){
  link.addClassName('selected');

  var otherLinks = link.siblings();

  for(var i = 0; i < otherLinks.lenght; i++){
     otherLinks[i].removeClassName('selected');     
  }

}

document.observe('dom:loaded', function(){
    $('menu').observe('click', function(event){
       event.stop();
       var link = Event.element(event); 
       selectLink(link);
       });
    });

---
<div id="menu">
<a href="url1" id="link1" class="">
<a href="url2" id="link2" class="">
<a href="url3" id="link3" class="">
</div>
```